# Autocomplete in the text box in PHP, Ajax and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Using Autocomplete text box to retrieve the data from the MySQL database table. my Ajax coding is working to retrieve the small amount of data. In my database table, I have more 300,000 records. The coding is not working when I used large data.

Please give suggestion about to retrieve a large data. 
Which method is best to retrieve the data.

See my coding. It works fine to retrieve a small amount of data

```
<input type="text" name="protein_name" id="protein_name">

$("#protein_name").keypress(function (e){   
   var protein_name = $("#protein_name").val(); 
    if(protein_name != "") {
        $.ajax({                    
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Protein_Main/protien_search',
                data: {protein_name: protein_name},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (res) {                                               
                        $("#protein_name").autocomplete({
                            source: res
                        });
                }
        });
    }   });
```

PHP Coding

```
$query =  $this->db->query("SELECT `Name_of_the_Protein` FROM `protein` WHERE Name_of_the_Protein Like '".$protein_name."%'");      
        $protein = $query->result();
```

echo json_encode($protein);

Comment: the best method in these cases is to return a max number of records (for example the first 10 records). Also because showing too many records is not usable for the user

Comment: use `limit` and `offset`

Comment: Try to add more context to your question and make it more precise. Also avoid falling into the [XY question trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - basically "you are asking the wrong question for the right problem"

Comment: @GiacomoM Its Autocomplete textbox.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, Did you understand my question?

Comment: @Athi you didnt ask any particular question. You asked something "the best method to do (teorically)"

Comment: For others not familiar with `lakhs`. 3 lakhs is 300,000.

Comment: Arent you missing an extra `%` at the start of LIKE  `Like '".$protein_name."%'");`. You have one at the end, but not before the protein_name variable

Comment: the best thing you can do is set limit 10 in your query

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete requires a few things.

- An input element

`<input type="text" id="nmRecipientSearch">`

- A couple of local javascript arrays:
  (One containing a list of potential selections, and another with numeric unique ids corresponding to each selection)

`var aryRecipientsFull=["Aaron","Adon","Andrew"];`

`var aryLrId=["1","2","3"];`

- A javascript .autocomplete handler bound to the input element:

  ```
  $( "#nm_recipient_search" ).autocomplete({ source: aryRecipientsFull,
  select: function( event, ui ) 
  {
      var numPosition,numLrId = 0;
      //Find the index position within the array for the selected item (e.g. Adon)
      numPosition=aryRecipientsFull.indexOf(ui.item.label);
      //Set a variable to the numeric value corresponding to the selected item (e.g. 2)
      numLrId=aryLrId[numPosition];
      //Populate a hidden input field (nm_lr_id) to the numeric value
      $('#nm_lr_id').val(numLrId);
      //Set the focus to the next field once a selection has been made
      $('#nm_text').focus();
  }
  });
  ```

A CSS style to ensure the autocomplete results appear above everything else:

`ul.ui-autocomplete
{
    z-index: 1100;
}`

A couple of things to consider:

- I'd recommend starting off using static arrays just to ensure that the UI looks okay
- If you need to (re)populate the arrays dynamically then you may need to bind a .keyup event to the search field, perform an AJAX call to a PHP page which then does a query as you've suggested, but make sure that you limit the number of resulting records (perhaps 10 or 20 records).
  Simply add "LIMIT 20" to the end of your SELECT query to achieve this.

I hope that helps.